# How to apply Bitwise AND operation for multiple images?

Tags: python, image, opencv, scikit-learn, imread

I need to do use bitAnd operation with img1 and each image of the directory. I read each image as img2.

```
img1 = np.zeros((600, 400, 3), np.uint8)
center_coordinates = (320, 200)
axesLength = (300, 80)  
angle = 150 
startAngle = 0
endAngle = 360
color = (255, 255, 255)
thickness = -1
img1 = cv2.ellipse(img1,center_coordinates,axesLength,angle,startAngle,endAngle, color, thickness)
i =1
for filename in glob.glob(r'C:/Users/HRMini/MY PRACTICE/Background Removal/PalmReading/croppedCHD_FM/Critical1/*.jpg'):
    img2 = cv2.imread(filename)
    bitAnd = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img1)
    cv2.imshow("img1", img1)
    cv2.imshow("img2", img2)
    cv2.imshow('bitAnd',bitAnd)   
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    i +=1
```

My code is not working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-d9a04cb32013> in <module>
     13     img2 = cv2.imread(filename)
     14 
---> 15     bitAnd = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img1)
     16 
     17     cv2.imshow("img1", img1)

error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:229: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op'
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'code is not working'?

Comment: ---> 15     bitAnd = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img1)
     16 
     17     cv2.imshow("img1", img1)

error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:229: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op'

Comment: Do the images have the same size of 600x400 and 3 channels? The error message looks like it could be related to this.

Comment: Is it possible to apply bitwise-and in opencv to 3-channel color images?

Comment: @ai2ys yes, it is possible to apply bitwise and to images with 3 channels. I think the problem is with image's sizes. Try printing image shapes before and operation.

Comment: [mre] is required. this code is broken from the indentation already.

Comment: @ai2ys Thank you!. it's the problem. I need to apply for all images in the directory. how to do this?

Comment: break the question down into subtasks. show us your research into that question. you know of `glob` already, so what's the hurdle?

Comment: You could apply the resize operation directly after reading the image from disk as a preprocessing step before applying the bitwise-AND. Do the image sizes all differ or are they the same but different than 600x400?

Comment: @ai2ys your proposed edit removes vital information from the post. this is considered vandalism. *do not do that*.

Comment: @ai2ys ok. yes , size of all the images are 600x400. Thank you!!!